# MySQL 1045 exception

Tags: python, mysql, django, exception

I use Django 1.3.1 & Python 2.7.2 and I'm trying to deploy a project locally with nginx.

Something wrong with `manage.py` after executing the first command. For example: the first command is:

```
$ python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=7782
```

and it works correctly. But when I try to execute any command after that, like `syncdb` or anything else (`runserver`, `validate`, `runfcgi`, etc...), I get strange exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 88, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 102, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 338, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 250, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 322, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

I don't know what the reason is. In `settings.py` all MySQL access parameters (`user`, `pass`, `dbname` & `host`) are written correctly (`syncdb` succeed).

**Note:** if I copy the project directory for example to "project2" and rename it to original "project", the problem disappears for the first `manage.py` command I exectue, after that, I see the exceptions again.

I have another django projects deployed in the same way, using same django & python, but they work without any problem.

Anybody knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Is your other Django project is set up on the same server/computer?

If it is, check your commas when you giving your db credentials and compare with the one which is running.